# Autologin on Apache/Website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, ldap

I need to export a specific website monthly as pdf. To execute the task on Ubuntu automatically I used a script that used to login itself on my website with https://user:pass@server but that doesnt work anymore.

Is there a way to autologin a specific IP like my Ubuntuserver on that website?
Like a specific apache configuration/ htaccess or anything?

The login is managed with LDAP

Thanks in advance

Comment: Passing the username and the password over querystring looks to be extremely bad and unsafe.

If you are trying to retrieve an object, why don't you use wget and you specify the user name and password over there?

More information here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/29079/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-to-wget

Comment: I actually fixed the login via URL by changing
    "AllowOverride AuthConfig"
to
    "AllowOverride All"
The script only works like that and I cant get the website with wget to gather the "dynamic" content